# How to make an image resizable when clicked inside a div without jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image-processing

I have a div and inside that there's an image. Now when I click the image I can get the image by `$(this)` and a border is displayed to let the user know that it can be resized.

html:

```
<div id="content">
    <p>Something <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/> Lorem expetendis .</p>
</div>
```

js:

```
$("#content img").on("click", function () {
    $(this).addClass("resize_handler");
});
```

Then I though of getting the initial x and y axis on `mousedown` and compare it to the `mousemove`. And then change the height/width of the image accordingly.

```
$(document).mousemove(function (event) {
    if (clicking == true) {
        x_axis = event.pageX;
        y_axis = event.pageY;
        delta_x_axis = x_axis - initial_x_axis;
        delta_y_axis = initial_y_axis - y_axis;
    }
});
```

Check out [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Karlss/jmyem32r/1/).

But it didn't help either, because as I try to drag, the image gets selected. How to make the image resizable when clicked with its aspect ratio? I would really appreciate your help and guidance. Thank you.

Comment: you can do it with Jquery UI -- http://jsfiddle.net/0qLk37jo/

Comment: @Tasos "without jquery UI"...

Comment: what are you using to drag the pic? because if it its jquery UI  it might be a better solution. Anyway To prevent the click while you drag you can use (event.preventDefault()) in your drag function --- http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jmyem32r/4/.

You should do your enhance, now it looks really ugly, but main principle is shown. To make a draggable behaviour, you should use a `boolean` switcher that is toggled with image `mousedown` event, and document `mouseup`. Also you should cancel default `mousedown` behaviour by calling `event.preventDefault` method.

```
 $(document).ready(function (event) {

    var x_axis;
    var y_axis;
    var initial_x_axis;
    var initial_y_axis;
    var isDragging = false; 
    $('#content img').mousedown(function (event) {        
        event.preventDefault();  
        isDragging = true;                      
        initial_x_axis = event.pageX;
        initial_y_axis = event.pageY;        
        $("#initial").text("initial-x: " + initial_x_axis + ", initial-y: " + initial_y_axis);
        $(this).addClass("resize_handler");
   });

    $(document).mouseup(function () {        
        isDragging = false;
    });

    $(document).mousemove(function (event) {
        if(isDragging) {
        x_axis = event.pageX;
        y_axis = event.pageY;
        var newWidth = $('#content img')[0].width / (initial_x_axis / x_axis);
        $('#content img').css('width', newWidth + 'px');            
    }             
});
```

});